# create a collapsible menu or spry menu using only CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, spry

i want to create a collapsible menu or even better a spry menu using just css/HTML. I want to use it on eBay but javascript/jquery is not allowed. I have seen it on other peoples eBay.

A spry menu would be best but this is probably not possible without javascript

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post the code you have created for this so far and tell us what isn't working for you.

Comment: javascript/jquery is not allowed on ebay but you can still use them if you need to use by different method there is always a different way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Pure CSS based menu then

**try this** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/xYFmh/) http://jsfiddle.net/gajjuthechamp/xYFmh/

**Source:** http://purecssmenu.com/

Comment: +1 for cool - IE7 is showing IE6 comments (probably fixable?) but all in all nice find.  Saving code for future.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at **[100 Great CSS Menu Tutorials](http://www.noupe.com/css/100-great-css-menu-tutorials.html)**